# What is the recommended way to report errors from custom WinRT component?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I'm authoring a custom C++ WinRT component library to be consumed by third parties. I'm unable to determine what the 'best practices' are for reporting/propagating runtime error conditions from my library.

I've found this article which details best practices for handling exceptions and crossing the WinRT ABI via HRESULTs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/error-handling.

However I'm unclear what to do for custom (exceptional) errors. I'd like to follow modern c++ practices and throw std::runtime_errors, but the WinRT documentation says that's reserved for mapping standard library errors to the 'E_FAIL' HRESULT. Should I be following the COM model and implementing custom HRESULT values, just for the sake of throwing them?

Comment: The recommended way to report recoverable errors is not to throw an exception but rather report the error in an in-API way, e.g., by returning a Status enum. The recommendation for Windows Runtime objects is that exceptions be thrown only for unrecoverable errors, and that you call `RoOriginateError` with a descriptive message explaining what the problem is. Since exceptions are nonrecoverable, it doesn't really matter what exception you throw -- it's going to crash the app either way. (In the page you linked, read the paragraph that starts "Don't throw an exception that you expect to catch.")

Comment: Hey Raymond -- thanks. The guidance on catching is clear here, but it feels a little fuzzy in the context of authoring a runtime component for others to consume. In some cases it's hard to tell whether a third party should consider a given error exceptional or not. What I'm hearing is it's always best to bias towards error passing, and reserve exceptions for the cases that are obviously unrecoverable and/or programming errors.

Comment: Yes, that's the guidance. I'll see what I can do to clarify the documentation. Thanks for calling it out.

Comment: Sure -- not sure whether it's a discrepancy in the docs though. I'm also relatively new to the basics of exceptions, like when and when not to throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw a `winrt::hresult_error`, with hresult code and error message. You can also throw an exception inherited from it. The code generated by cppwinrt will convert your exception to HRESULT.

Comment: This is what I've been leaning towards. I guess that means I either need to 'hijack' some existing HRESULT that's close enough to the problem, throw a generic E_FAIL, or implement my own set of HRESULT values.

Comment: Here are all  [HRESULT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx) values defined by microsoft. I think you will find one close enough. If you want to implement your own set, remember to obey the [rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231198.aspx).